# Can we write a generic type in TypeScript that converts a Record to a type that we get when we specify `as const`?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

Let's say, I have `const foo = { myKey: 'myValue' } as const`

Then, `typeof foo` is `{ readonly myKey: 'myValue' }`

If I have type `MyType = Record<string, string>`, I want to write a modifier (let's say Modify ) which does follows...

`type ModifiedMyType = Modify<MyType>`

`const foo: ModifiedMyType = { myKey: 'myValue' }`

In this case, I have **NOT** specified it as const like before. But, I want `typeof foo`   to be
`{ readonly myKey: 'myValue' }`

Comment: Try `Readonly` modifier. `type Foo = Readonly<{ a: 1 }>`

Comment: If you mean that `const foo: ModifiedMyType = { ⋯ }` should somehow adapt to the contents of the initializer, then that's not possible.  What is the use case?  If it's that you just want to *check* the initializer against `MyType`, then you could use the `satisfies` operator as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQ00YW) and I could write up an answer explaining if that works for you.  If your use case is something else, could you [edit] to mention it explicitly?  Otherwise the answer here would just be "you can't".  Let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mapped type along with the readonly modifier.

```
type Modify<T> = {
  readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};

type MyType = Record<string, string>;
type ModifiedMyType = Modify<MyType>;

const foo: ModifiedMyType = { myKey: 'myValue' };
```